Embedded systems using antenna for stable digital communication
I want to make use of PIC16F554 for wireless communication between antennas.
I tried transferring voice by modulating the signal in AM, but the incoming voice was too bad, so a noise reduction by using a capacitor was a crucial need. Also, after this handling the incoming signal became to weak. I suppose that the antenna was too short for proper transmission with crystal properties of voice at frequencies between 1MHz-100MHz.
I was thinking about transferring digital signals between antennas by using a PIC which has a 20MHz processor. The antennas will be driven at 433MHz and the demodulated signal which will be a digital one, will have between 100kHz-1MHz. The demodulated signal will excite the PIC and the processing should begin after that.
Normally, when I would use a 433MHz antenna, which I could buy from shops, I prefer to make one myself. It should have length of 70cm when using a full wave.
My question is the following:
As tried to transfer voice between antennas like described above, there were many noises because the length of antenna was not at the preferable length, so the efficiency was too low. What if the antenna is at full length, will it be possible to get digital signals at high contrast without noises?
https://www.embedded.com/embedded/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2023/04/2304pervices_f1.png


Regarding the antenna, it doesn't seem to me that your procedure is correct. The most common and simple antennas are the Hertzian or half-wave and the Marconian or rod. The Hertzian (horizontal) is a dipole and is made up of two branches each λ/4 long (= 17.31cm, for f=433MHz) at the terminals where the power supply is applied in resonance the radiation resistance is Ri= 73Ω, if it is filiform then Ri=64Ω while the gain G=1.65. The Marconian antenna is made up of a single branch λ/4 long (17.31cm) and the radiation resistance Ri=36.5Ω, if filiform Ri=32Ω.

"there were many noises because the length of antenna was not at the preferable length"  How do you know? There's a whole lot of things in the whole RF path that could be causing such problems. Impedance matching, inaccurate frequency, injected DC etc etc.
